# Inject a dependency in a SeriLog enricher with autofac

Tags: autofac, serilog

I want to create a [Serilog Enricher](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) injecting some data from a dependency.  How can autofac inject my dependency into an enricher?

This is my container setup:

```
builder.Register((c, p) =>
{
  return new LoggerConfiguration()
   .Enrich.FromLogContext()
   .Enrich.With<MyEnricherWhichCanAddMoreDataFromADependency>()
   // ...
  .CreateLogger();
}).As<ILogger>();
```

While the enricher would look something like

```
public class MyEnricherWhichCanAddMoreDataFromADependency : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public MyEnricherWhichCanAddMoreDataFromADependency(IDependency d) 
    { ... do stuff with the dependency ... }
}
```

Constructor injection does not seem to work. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enrich `With<T>` all it's doing, literally, [is calling `new T()`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Configuration/LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration.cs#L69).

If you want to pass the enricher through DI you need to do that yourself.

```
builder.Register((c, p) =>
{
  var e = c.Resolve<MyEnricherWhichCanAddMoreDataFromADependency>();
  return new LoggerConfiguration()
   .Enrich.FromLogContext()
   .Enrich.With(e)
   // ...
  .CreateLogger();
}).As<ILogger>();
```